# react native : when I yarn run iOS, there are lots of error message(but build is successed)

Tags: react-native

[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/HyxEpFyAx_g)

all of them is log messages.
It can be build.

but I don't know why it happened.

Comment: Please check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It is unclear what you are asking and videos' are not the way to go.

Comment: iOS logs a lot during build so I generally wouldn't worry about it as long as the build succeeds.